# MFC CFile write

Tags: c++, mfc, cfile

I am using MFC to write a measurement application. On the first run, I got my data written on first column and on to next row and next row.

Here's the question. On the second run, how do I write my data on the second column?

```
CFile DataFile(m_strPathName, CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeCreate);
sprintf_s(File,"%d,%f,%e\r\n",i , position, buffer1);
GetLength = strlen(File);
DataFile.Write(File, GetLength);
```

buffer1 is the power value extracted from the measurement hardware.

Comment: Does it have to grow by column? That is very awkward and inefficient for a file. But they can easily grow by adding a row at the end.

Comment: First data would grow in first column and second data would grow in second column. That's what I mean. @ScottMcP-MVP

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think ,you should design a format for the file. when you write, you should use a offset to determine where to write.For example ,the column length is a particular value and the same to the row value ,like this:

```
---column1----|----column2----|---column3----|...
---row1-------|----row2-------|----row3------|..
....
```

when your write a column or a row, just locate the "|" position,then write your value .

Answer (score 0):

You mean write data by column, which is just next to the first column? That could not be done sequentially. Since file is a stream structure, we can't insert data to the middle of a file, too.

An alternative way is this:

1. Create a new file with write and append permisson.
2. Read one row sequentially from the original file, write it to the new file.
3. Write one row of the second column to the new file.
4. Repeat the step 2 and 3 util the original file reach the end.
5. Swap the file name of the original file and the new file.